# Decidability involving functions

Tags: computability

I'm trying to figure out how to resolve this exercise.
$$
\Sigma = \{a,b\}
$$
is a set while
$$
\mathcal{P}(\Sigma^*)
$$
is the partition of sigma star.
I have a function f:
$$ f: \mathcal{P}(\Sigma^*) = \mathcal{P}(\Sigma^*)$$
such that for all subset P of sigma star, if P is not semidecidable and not decidable, then f(P) is a decidable set and
$$ P \subseteq f(P) $$

Show that any such function f is not an injection.